# How to print more than one values but without printing full list from a nested list in dart?

Tags: arrays, list, dart

Here it prints only 20. But I want to print 20 and 30 without 10. How to do that?

```dart
void main() {
  List<List<int>> list = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [10, 20, 30]
  ];
  print(list[1][1]); // 20
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot since it makes it harder for people to copy your code into their development environment, which is often needed for playing around different solutions before posting one.

Answer (score 0):

You can access items in a list by calling their indices.
You can do :

```
 print('${list[1][1]} ${list[1][2]}');
```

or

```
print(list[1][1]);
print(list[1][2]);
```

you can also create a sublist and iterate through it :

```
list[1].sublist(1).forEach(print);
```